# How to make a percentage of the type column in a histogram?

Tags: pandas, histogram

The pandas dataframe is as the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 4], ['B', 12], ['B', 50], ['B', 19], ['A', 39], ['B', 12], ['A', 22], ['B', 33], ['B', 14], ['B', 43], ['A', 50], ['B', 34], ['A', 22],  ['B', 60],
              ['A', 14], ['B', 31], ['B', 40], ['B', 38], ['A', 21], ['B', 41], ['A', 23], ['B', 45], ['B', 25], ['B', 32], ['A', 10], ['B', 31], ['A', 21],  ['B', 51]])
df.columns = ['Type', 'Distance']
```

df.head(2):

```
  Type  Distance

0    A         4

1    B        12
```

Expectation:

```
1) create a histogram with bins=10, 
2) y is the (amount of A in this bin)/(amount of A + amount of B in this bin)
```

For example, in bin 10-20:

```
df1 = df[df['Distance'].between(10,20)]
df1.head(10)
```

There are 6 rows in this distance bin 10-20:

```
Type    Distance

1   B   12

3   B   19

5   B   12

8   B   14

14  A   14

24  A   10
```

Hence,

1. amount of A in bin (10,20): 2
2. amount of B in bin (10,20): 4
3. amount of A in bin (10,20) / ((amount of A in bin (10,20) + amount of B in bin (10,20))
   = 2 / (2+4) = 33.3%
4. So for for bin 10-20, the y value should be 33.3%.

The above step applies to other bin to calculate the percentage of A out of (A+B).

I also need to keep the X bin be 10, not float or else.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you should `pivot_table` to reshape your data, compute the bins in pandas using `cut` and then plot:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Distance', columns='Type', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
bins = range(0, int(df2.index.max())+1, 10)
df3 = df2.groupby(pd.cut(df2.index, bins=bins)).sum()
df3['A'].div(df3.sum(1)).plot.bar(width=1)
```

output:

[image: A/B]

```
>>> df3
Type          A  B
(3.944, 9.6]  1  0
(9.6, 15.2]   2  3
(15.2, 20.8]  0  1
(20.8, 26.4]  5  1
(26.4, 32.0]  0  3
(32.0, 37.6]  0  2
(37.6, 43.2]  1  4
(43.2, 48.8]  0  1
(48.8, 54.4]  1  2
(54.4, 60.0]  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I haven't described the issue clearly, I'm sorry. I want to keep the Y value be  the percentage of A out of (A+B) in each bin of 10. And the bin 10 can't be reshaped as well. I have edited the problem description for your better understanding. In this way, how can I achieve this goal, please?

Comment: @Sky best if you provide a schematic of the expected graph output with proper values

Comment: it looks more or less like what I did, except I computed the bins automatically and you want to define them manually, you just need to change that in `cut`

Comment: Thank you! But the current bin is 5.6. How to change in cut to let the bins be exactly 10, please?

Comment: I've seen that you've set the bins be 10 in "cut" function, but the output shows the bin is 5.6. I'm confused about it, sorry. If I want to let the bin in output be exactly 10, how should I change it in "cut"? Thanks!

Comment: @Sky `bins=10` means 10 bins of equal size, if you want ranges of 10 you have to pass a list/range (check the docs). See my update

Comment: Thank you! But when I ran this line: bin_range = range(0, df2.index.max()+1, 10) , it returned an error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: This means you have floats in you column, wrap `df2.index.max()` in `int`: `int(df2.index.max())`